# write csv with two header lines?

Tags: r

Can I export a data.frame to csv with two header lines, one line for the column names, and one line for the comments on the column names? For instance,

```
d <- data.frame(a=c(1,3,4), b=c(5,6,7))
comment(d$a) <- "MWh"
comment(d$b) <- "%"
write.csv(d, "myfile.csv", ???)
```

Any hint appreciated, also on alternatives to comment()!

Comment: Use `write.table` and `append=TRUE`.

Comment: I strongly advise you to use another way to annotate your table. If your csv file is going to be use by humans opening up the file in a spreadsheet you will be OK. But the instance anyone wants to do anything useful such as read it into a database or R the fact that there are two rows making up the header is going to inflict lots of pain upon them. That said, I would like to find a way to append an explanation to a data frame. Do you know of a way to append explanations or units to a .Rdata file that contains a data frame?

Comment: I would just add a few columns starting with a unique character (like /* or #). Those can easily be skipped when reading the data (into R) by the means of the first char(s) or just by skipping first x rows. `sink` seems like it could cope with that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to preserve the numeric nature of the data, I don't think we can do it with an easy one-liner (the answer provided by @Chase changes the data type to character), but we can do it via a few manipulations that write `names(d)` and the two comments out to the file first and then uses `write.table()` to write the csv data lines, appending to the file we just wrote the names and comments to:

```
write.csv3 <- function(d, file) {
    opts <- options(useFancyQuotes = FALSE)
    on.exit(options(opts))
    h1 <- paste(dQuote(c("", names(d))), collapse = ",")
    h2 <- paste(dQuote(c("", comment(d$a), comment(d$b))), collapse = ",")
    writeLines(paste(h1, h2, sep = "\n"), file)
    write.table(d, file, sep = ",", append = TRUE, col.names = FALSE)
}
```

Here is an example:

```
> d <- data.frame(a=c(1,3,4), b=c(5,6,7))
> comment(d$a) <- "MWh"
> comment(d$b) <- "%"
> d
  a b
1 1 5
2 3 6
3 4 7
> write.csv3(d, file = "myfile.csv")
```

Which produces the following file:

```
$ cat myfile.csv 
"","a","b"
"","MWh","%"
"1",1,5
"2",3,6
"3",4,7
```

compared to that produced by @Chase's Answer:

```
$ cat output.csv 
"","a","b"
"1","MHh","%"
"2","1","5"
"3","3","6"
"4","4","7"
```

Between the two, you should have sufficient options.

Comment: If you want to read the produced data back into R, the data will be of class `factor` or `character` (depending on `stringsAsFactors`), but I'm presuming this is more of a one-way thing from R to something else.

Comment: Great solution; this helps a lot!

Answer (score 6):

Would `rbind()`ing your comments to the top of your `data.frame` be an option before writing out? If you make a new object, you won't impact the structure or class of the existing columns.

```
d <- data.frame(a=c(1,3,4), b=c(5,6,7))
output <- rbind(c("MHh", "%"), d)
write.csv(output, "output.csv")
```

Answer (score 2):

I have some small modifications to the excellent answer provided by @Gavin Simpson.

- It's not obvious in the OP whether row names are required. I have removed these and amended the header offset
- using `fwrite()` from the data.table package instead of `write.table()` reduces the processing time to 1/10 compared with the base function.

```
library(data.table)
write.csv3 <- function(data, file, header) {
  opts <- options(useFancyQuotes = FALSE)
  on.exit(options(opts)) 
  h1 <- paste(dQuote(c(header)), collapse = ",")
  h2 <- paste(dQuote(c(names(data))), collapse = ",")
  writeLines(paste(h1, h2, sep = "\n"), file)
  fwrite(data, file, sep = ",", append = TRUE, col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
}
```

Comment: I like your modification, but I think your function is missing an argument: header.

Comment: Good spot! Edited.